# show outlook appointment ribbon in calendar tools

Tags: calendar, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon, appointment

I created (by RibbonDesigner) new outlook ribbon that appears in the window of an appointment.

RibbonType:
Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment,Microsoft.Outlook.MeetingRequest.Read

I want to add this Ribbon to CalendarItems near 'Appointment' tab , when appointment is selected from the calendar view

[[Location where I want to put the ribbon][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AWDy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AWDy.png)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ribbon designer doesn't provide all the features of the Fluent UI, in some cases you need to use the Ribbon XML to get things working. See [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) to get started quickly.

Looks like you need to add a new contextual tab to the Calendar Tools of the Explorer window. For example:

```
 <contextualTabs>
  <tabSet idMso="TabSetAppointment">
   <tab id="YourTab">
     ... 
   </tab>
  </tabSet>
 </contextualTabs>
```

Read more about that in the similar forum thread - [How to get Calendar Tools Ribbon through VSTO Outlook Addin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1059a393-a2d8-4a3c-9fe9-b426c6352ee1/how-to-get-calendar-tools-ribbon-through-vsto-outlook-addin?forum=vsto).

You may also find the [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548010%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

Comment: see my next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435908/show-outlook-ribbon-near-appointmenttab