# show outlook ribbon near appointmentTab

Tags: calendar, outlook, outlook-addin, ribbon, ribbonx

I created new outlook ribbon by ribbonXML

I want to show this Ribbon

**1.** in Appointment\Meeting window

**2.** in CalendarItems near 'Appointment' tab , when appointment is selected from the calendar view

I can display the two options but not together in one Ribbon.

"contextualTabs" - displays the tab in calendarItems,

"TabAddins" - displays the tab only in appointment\meeting window according to the C# code

I want this Ribbon will be displayed in both of these cases.How can I do it?

My Code:

```
<ribbon>
  <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="MyTab">
      <group id="group1" label="save">
        <button id="btnSaveAs" onAction="btnSaveAs_Click" 
                imageMso="FileSave"/>
      </group>
    </tab>
  </tabs>

 <contextualTabs>      
   <tabSet idMso="TabSetAppointment">
     <tab id="TabAppointment" label="MyTab">
       <group id="MyGroup" label="save">
         <button id="btnSaveAppAs" onAction="btnSaveAs_Click" label="save" 
                 imageMso="FileSave"/>
       </group>
     </tab>
   </tabSet>
 </contextualTabs>
</ribbon>
```

C#: (cause showing the ribbon only in appointment\meeting window)

```
public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
    {
        if(ribbonID=="Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment")
            return GetResourceText("OutlookAddIn.Ribbon.xml");
        if (ribbonID == "Microsoft.Outlook.MeetingRequest")
            return GetResourceText("OutlookAddIn.Ribbon.xml");
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I put the two options in two separate xml files and repaired getcustomUI

Ribbon.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"     onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
<ribbon>
  <tabs>
    <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="MyTab">
      <group id="group1" label="save">
        <button id="btnSaveAs" onAction="btnSaveAs_Click" 
                imageMso="FileSave"/>
      </group>
    </tab>
  </tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

CalendarToolsRibbon.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"     onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
<ribbon>
 <contextualTabs>      
   <tabSet idMso="TabSetAppointment">
     <tab id="TabAppointment" label="MyTab">
       <group id="MyGroup" label="save">
         <button id="btnSaveAppAs" onAction="btnSaveAs_Click" label="save" 
             imageMso="FileSave"/>
       </group>
    </tab>
   </tabSet>
  </contextualTabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

C#:

```
   public string GetCustomUI(string ribbonID)
    {
        if (ribbonID == "Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment")
            return GetResourceText("OutlookAddIn.Ribbon.xml");
        if (ribbonID == "Microsoft.Outlook.MeetingRequest.Read")
            return GetResourceText("OutlookAddIn.Ribbon.xml");
        return GetResourceText("OutlookAddIn.CalendarToolsRibbon.xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to return an appropriate Ribbon XML markup for the Explorer ribbon ID value. Try to debug the `GetCustomUI` method and see what values are passed.

Read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, In debug , ribbonID="Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer" when outlook is opened. when I change to calendar view the breakpoint doesn't hit again until I open a window. How should I proceed?